# How to synchronize with the "future" when extracting data from the database

Tags: java, asynchronous, future, iasyncresult

There is an asynchronous construction. I would like to continue processing after reading from the database here. I tried to use the "while" cycle as follows, but it didn't. Endless loop. If there is no "while" loop, it is asynchronous, but it doesn't work for me.

```
private XmlOperations fetchAttributeFromDB(RequestContext context, 
                   XmlOperations invCnclAttributes,String orderId) {

    String strSQL = "select bankStan,bankBatch,provBank from transactionHistory where orderId='"+orderId+"' limit 1";
    DBClientService dbClientService = DBClientService.getService(context);
    try {
        Future<List<JsonArray>> futureHistory = dbClientService.ExecuteQuery(strSQL);
        futureHistory.setHandler(sqlResult -> {
            List<JsonArray> result = futureHistory.result();
            invCnclAttributes.addAttribute("bankStan", result.get(0).getString(0));
            invCnclAttributes.addAttribute("bankBatch", result.get(0).getString(1));
            invCnclAttributes.addAttribute("provBank", result.get(0).getString(2));
            futureHistory.complete();
        });
        while(!futureHistory.isComplete());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return invCnclAttributes;
}
```

Comment: `Future` should already be fully synchronized.

Comment: As you know, "Future" is asynchronous.  That's the whole point.  It sounds like all you need is to add a `future.get()`.  Do *NOT* use a "polling loop"! Get rid of that "while()"!!!  ALSO: look here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

Comment: If you really want to block/wait here, you can do `futureHistory.get()`. But the preferred way is to produce another Future using `thenApply` or `thenCompose`.  `Future<TheThreeAttributes> results = futureHistory.thenApply(result -> new TheThreeAttributes(result.get(0).getString(0), .....)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you can use Java 8 (which supports CompletableFuture and Streams) or Java 9 (which also supports the "Reactive" Flow API).

Let's assume you can use Java 8 and feel reasonably comfortable with Futures.

Then you want to use `CompletableFuture`.  And, as Thilo pointed out, you *definitely* want to use `thenApply` or `thenCompose` to compose your list.

Under *NO* circumstances do you want to use a "polling loop", if you can at all avoid it.

Here is an excellent, short tutorial that will tell you the basic concepts, and give you example code:

[Baeldung: Guide To CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)

Here is a book I've personally found very useful for understanding the new Java concurrency APIs:

[Modern Java in Action: Lambdas, streams, functional and reactive programming 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617293563)

<= The 2nd edition also covers Java 9 and Java 10